# "No source available for main()" while debugging in Eclipse IDE

Tags: catkin, ros-groovy, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm new to ros groovy and using catkin. I created a workspace, a catkin package with catkin_create_pkg and an eclipse project with `catkin_make --force-cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"`. Now in my workspace I have the src, devel and build folder and I can run the program in eclipse IDE. Therefore I need to choose "Run configurations" -> Created new Launch and browsed the binary. But if I try to debug it, eclipse doesn't show the source code, if it stops at a breakpoint and I just get `No source available for main()`.

Does anyone have a solution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64596/%22no-source-available-for-main()%22-while-debugging-in-eclipse-ide/) by [Sonne](https://answers.ros.org/users/5074/sonne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2013-06-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, found the solution. Would be nice if this maybe could be a hint in the tutorial for beginners like me ;)

Just cd to build directory and then use

```
cmake ../src -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

Now in Eclipse degugging should work.

---

Originally posted by [Sonne](https://answers.ros.org/users/5074/sonne/) with karma: 76 on 2013-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-06-11**:
What tutorial were you following?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-06-11**:
I'm not familiar with using Eclipse, but it would be nice if you added a note for eclipse users on what ever tutorial you were following.

**Comment by [Sonne](https://answers.ros.org/users/5074/sonne/) on 2013-06-11**:
Hi joq and William, I followed the catkin tutorials http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials and http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs .Here in section "2.2 Catkin-y Approach" is a link to http://answers.ros.org/question/52013/catkin-and-eclipse/ but didn't realized thats also the solution for my problem.

**Comment by [Sonne](https://answers.ros.org/users/5074/sonne/) on 2013-06-12**:
@William Ok, I added a note on the http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs

**Comment by [Lucy](https://answers.ros.org/users/6253/lucy/) on 2013-08-29**:
@Sonne I have looked everywhere for this answer.  THANK YOU!!!!!  I am new to CMake and I'm trying to debug a project in Eclipse that is build with CMake.  Your command did the trick.  :-)